# Is using Magento overkill?

Tags: php, magento

I contracted a programmer to create a site for me. It's a site where I can centralize other sellers of clothes and show it off via galleries, perhaps you can think of it as ebay without the online payments/bidding, but focused on apparel. The sellers merely post their wares. Buyer transactions are done directly with the sellers off the site. My programmer insists on using Magento. I am researching around and found this site: http://w3techs.com/ and it's pretty useful for a non-techie like me to learn that sites like ebay and amazon don't use Magento.

I've read on other stack threads that using CMS/Magento falls more on the plus side of the equation. I'm ok with that fact, but I would just like to know if it's not overkill to use it for my site, given the functions it will offer sellers-- functions which are way less than what ebay and amazon offer and *they* don't use Magento?

Though I know it's on the plus side, my concern about using Magento is that it uses up too much resources, thus much much more expensive hosting-wise. I had a hosting company do a costing for 100 visitors and the hosting package recommended to accommodate them is VERY expensive. I am wondering if the hosting requirements would be comparatively lower if the site didn't use Magento?

Thanks for any input. I'm on very unfamiliar territory here.

Comment: This is off-topic for this site, but I can't help but want to offer some advice. It sounds like your entire business will rely on your site. In that case, you don't just need a programmer, you need a partner you can trust who knows what they're doing and cares about the idea.  You may want to read this: http://swombat.com/2012/1/19/idea-reach-cofounder-myth

Comment: It's so pointless to compare your site to juggernauts likes ebay and amazon.

Comment: Magento uses more resources then other shoping carts, but that is a consequence of offering more flexibility/functionality/extendability, etc. So there are tradeoffs. Ebay and amazon don't use magento, they use custom systems that can cope with the demands of their business. Your business is very different, you won't be getting 100,000 orders a week to start off with, so no point basing your decision on what they use.

Comment: eBay and Amazon use custom programming and massive amounts of horsepower to do a different job from what Magento offers. It's a comparison of a Terex mine truck to your average Peterbilt dump truck. Depends on what you want to haul with your Peterbilt, maybe a little GMC Sierra is more in line if you don't plan on growth.

Comment: NickC, I apologize if this is OT. I was thinking who best to ask than the experts in this field themselves. I find it hard to get an objective opinion from programmers I've "interviewed" IRL.  Thanks for the help, tho. Actually, he's a mix of contracted and a partner as well-- I say contracted because he insisted on some cash payment, in addition to being a partner. I can't gauge if he wants to use Magento because it what he specializes in and is easier for him (didn't like the suggestion of from scratch programming), or if it's because using Magento makes the site overwhelmingly efficient.

Comment: bumperbox, Ben and Fiasco, hehe... I didn't mean to compare my modest operation to the giants :D I just needed a popular point of comparison to demonstrate how simple the site's features would be. And I was under the impression that Magento is for big/advanced sites, so I'm unsure if Magento for my site is overkill.

Comment: @stacker a multi-vendor ecommerce system is not "simple"